# Deep link opens up chrome web browser instead of the app on android

Tags: android, kotlin, deep-linking

I was learning about how to open up an android app using deep links. I followed this tutorial. But, I was unable to open the specific app. It opened the link in the chrome browser. I don't want to open the link in browser, but open the specific android app activity. What am I missing here?

https://www.kodeco.com/18330247-deep-links-in-android-getting-started

This is the link to the tutorial.

I have added the necessary intents as follows:

```
<activity
            android:name=".main.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <tools:validation testUrl="https://courseapp.com/guide" />

            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true" android:label="@string/app_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data
                    android:scheme="https"
                    android:host="courseapp.com"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true" android:label="@string/app_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data
                    android:scheme="http"
                    android:host="courseapp.com"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true" android:label="@string/app_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data
                    android:scheme="http"
                    android:host="courseapp.com"
                    android:pathPrefix="/guides"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true" android:label="@string/app_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data
                    android:scheme="https"
                    android:host="courseapp.com"
                    android:pathPrefix="/guides"/>
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
```

This is inside my MainActivity. I am calling this function from onCreate() function of the MainActivity.

```
private fun getDeepLinkParamsAndRoute() {
        val data: Uri? = intent?.data
        if (data != null) {
            val parameters: List<String> = data.pathSegments
            val params = parameters[parameters.size - 1]
            Log.i("MainActivity*********Deep Link", params)
        }
    }
```

When I run the adb command

```
 ./adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "https://courseapp.com/guides?id=123"
```

I see this
 `Status: ok LaunchState: UNKNOWN (0) Activity: com.android.chrome/org.chromium.chrome.browser.document.ChromeLauncherActivity WaitTime: 139 Complete`

Comment: same problem here.
If I try to open a hyperlink in chrome on the android api 28 device, it goes to webview test that it runs well, I think there is a problem with the chrome browser.(about sending the intent)